# why is junk data added to All Contacts in Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

Not sure how the junk data is being added to All Contacts. Ends up cleaning up every 1 month. Even asked Salesforce about this but did not get clear understanding.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what do you mean by junk data?  Do you mean the linked Data Extensions on Contact table? Or do you mean Contacts originating from Sales Cloud (Leads/Contacts/Users)?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple sources, from where contacts can “arrive”, depending on whether you use API based triggered sends, Synchronised Data Extensions, channels you utilise (email/sms/app) etc. 
It is described in more details [here on the help page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_definition_and_count_determination.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.dk%2F&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null).

If you need more precise guidance, please provide more clarification on what you mean by “junk”, and what you have done so far to reduce the number of unwanted contacts.